# Cannot write "ê" or "ë" in my keyboard with the ^-key on terminal applications, but I can on non-terminal applications

Tags: terminal, keyboard-layout, console

I use Manjaro, with i3 but the problem is also present with plasma.

For this message, I will call the `^`-key, the key to the right of the <kbd>p</kbd> on a French AZERTY keyboard, which has a `^` and `¨` and  can be used to write `^` or `¨`.

Since a few days, I cannot add `^` or `¨` accents to letters on my terminal (for example, with konsole or alacritty) such as

- `ê` with `^`-key then <kbd>e</kbd>
- `ë` with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd>
  The problem is also present on terminal applications such as nvim.

Nevertheless, this works for non-terminal applications such as firefox. This doesn't seem to be a problem of keyboards, my `/etc/`.
This doesn't work even if I push space or right after it.

I tried with another terminal (kitty) and the same problem appears.

Nevertheless, the `^`-key works perfectly on non-terminal applications such as firefox or discord.

Also, I can write the character `^` on the terminal using the combination <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.

Finally, note that if I use keyboard configurations that set the `^`-key as `^`, but don't allow to make nice combinations to write `¨` and `^` as accents on letters, I am able to use the touch on my terminal.
But I have no interest in that, because I only use the `^`-key to write accents on letters, not to just write `^`.

Do you have any idea what could be happening?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Here is my keyboard configuration file `/etc/default/keyboards` :

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="fr"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Here is my locales /etc/default/locale :

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Here is my i3 config file:

```
# i1 config file (v4)
#
# Please see https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html for a complete reference!
#
# This config file uses keycodes (bindsym) and was written for the QWERTY
# layout.
#
# To get a config file with the same key positions, but for your current
# layout, use the i3-config-wizard

# The modifier used all along this configuration file. It is the super key.
# Mod1 = Alt, Mod4 = super
set $mod Mod4

# local conf. Differ depending on the computer
include ~/.config/i3/local.conf

# A nice autotiling
# needs to use the script in https://github.com/nwg-piotr/autotiling
exec_always --no-startup-id autotiling


# Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
# is used in the bar {} block below.
# font pango:monospace 12
# This font is widely installed, provides lots of unicode glyphs, right-to-left
# text rendering and scalability on retina/hidpi displays (thanks to pango).
font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 14

# Start XDG autostart .desktop files using dex. See also
# https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Autostart
exec --no-startup-id dex --autostart --environment i3

# The combination of xss-lock, nm-applet and pactl is a popular choice, so
# they are included here as an example. Modify as you see fit.

# xss-lock grabs a logind suspend inhibit lock and will use i3lock to lock the
# screen before suspend. Use loginctl lock-session to lock your screen.
exec --no-startup-id xss-lock --transfer-sleep-lock -- i3lock --nofork

# NetworkManager is the most popular way to manage wireless networks on Linux,
# and nm-applet is a desktop environment-independent system tray GUI for it.
exec --no-startup-id nm-applet

# use these keys for focus, movement, and resize directions when reaching for
# the arrows is not convenient
set $up k
set $down j
set $left h
set $right l

# use Mouse+$mod to drag floating windows to their wanted position
floating_modifier $mod

# start a terminal
bindsym $mod+Return exec alacritty
bindsym $mod+t exec alacritty

# start applications
# bindsym $mod+Shift+f exec firefox
# bindsym $mod+Shift+z exec zathura
# terminal applications
# Cause i use konsole terminal...
# bindsym $mod+Shift+r exec konsole -e ranger
# bindsym $mod+Shift+n exec konsole -e nvim

# kill focused window
bindsym $mod+Shift+q kill

# start dmenu (a program launcher)
# bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id dmenu_run
# A more modern dmenu replacement is rofi:
set $rofi exec "rofi -modi drun,run -show drun -show-icons"

# some added scripts
set $rofi_scripts ~/.config/rofi
bindsym $mod+d exec "rofi -modi drun,run -show drun -show-icons"
# doesn't work
bindsym $mod+b exec $rofi_scripts/i3_switch_workspace.sh
bindsym $mod+Shift+b exec "rofi -show window -show-icons"

# There also is i3-dmenu-desktop which only displays applications shipping a
# .desktop file. It is a wrapper around dmenu, so you need that installed.
# bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop

# change focus
bindsym $mod+$left focus left
bindsym $mod+$down focus down
bindsym $mod+$up focus up
bindsym $mod+$right focus right

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym $mod+Left focus left
bindsym $mod+Down focus down
bindsym $mod+Up focus up
bindsym $mod+Right focus right

# move focused window
bindsym $mod+Shift+$left move left
bindsym $mod+Shift+$down move down
bindsym $mod+Shift+$up move up
bindsym $mod+Shift+$right move right

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym $mod+Shift+Left move left
bindsym $mod+Shift+Down move down
bindsym $mod+Shift+Up move up
bindsym $mod+Shift+Right move right

# split in horizontal orientation
bindsym $mod+Shift+v split h

# split in vertical orientation
bindsym $mod+v split v

# enter fullscreen mode for the focused container
bindsym $mod+f fullscreen toggle

# change container layout (stacked, tabbed, toggle split)
bindsym $mod+s layout stacking
bindsym $mod+w layout tabbed
bindsym $mod+e layout toggle split

# toggle tiling / floating
bindsym $mod+Shift+space floating toggle

# change focus between tiling / floating windows
bindsym $mod+space focus mode_toggle

# focus the parent container
bindsym $mod+a focus parent
# focus the child container
bindsym $mod+z focus child

# Show the next scratchpad window or hide the focused scratchpad window.
# If there are multiple scratchpad windows, this command cycles through them.
bindsym $mod+c scratchpad show
# move the currently focused window to the scratchpad
bindsym $mod+Shift+c move scratchpad

# Define names for default workspaces for which we configure key bindings later on.
# We use variables to avoid repeating the names in multiple places.
set $ws1 "1"
set $ws2 "2"
set $ws3 "3"
set $ws4 "4"
set $ws5 "5"
set $ws6 "6"
set $ws7 "7"
set $ws8 "8"
set $ws9 "9"
set $ws10 "10"

# switch to workspace
bindsym $mod+1 workspace number $ws1
bindsym $mod+2 workspace number $ws2
bindsym $mod+3 workspace number $ws3
bindsym $mod+4 workspace number $ws4
bindsym $mod+5 workspace number $ws5
bindsym $mod+6 workspace number $ws6
bindsym $mod+7 workspace number $ws7
bindsym $mod+8 workspace number $ws8
bindsym $mod+9 workspace number $ws9
bindsym $mod+0 workspace number $ws10

#navigate workspaces next / previous, as for the navigation after the f/t
bindsym $mod+semicolon workspace next
bindsym $mod+comma workspace prev

# move focused container to workspace
bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace number $ws1
bindsym $mod+Shift+2 move container to workspace number $ws2
bindsym $mod+Shift+3 move container to workspace number $ws3
bindsym $mod+Shift+4 move container to workspace number $ws4
bindsym $mod+Shift+5 move container to workspace number $ws5
bindsym $mod+Shift+6 move container to workspace number $ws6
bindsym $mod+Shift+7 move container to workspace number $ws7
bindsym $mod+Shift+8 move container to workspace number $ws8
bindsym $mod+Shift+9 move container to workspace number $ws9
bindsym $mod+Shift+0 move container to workspace number $ws10


# For example, if you are on the workspace 1 and you hit $mod+2, you’ll switch to workspace 2.
# Then, if you hit $mod+2 again, you’ll go back to your previous workspaces, workspace 1.
workspace_auto_back_and_forth no

# reload the configuration file
# bindsym $mod+Shift+c reload
bindsym $mod+r restart
# restart i3 inplace (preserves your layout/session, can be used to upgrade i3)
# exit i3 (logs you out of your X session)
bindsym $mod+Shift+e exec "i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -B 'Yes, exit i3' 'i3-msg exit'"

# resize window (you can also use the mouse for that)
mode "resize" {
        # These bindings trigger as soon as you enter the resize mode

        # Pressing left will shrink the window’s width.
        # Pressing right will grow the window’s width.
        # Pressing up will shrink the window’s height.
        # Pressing down will grow the window’s height.
        bindsym $left       resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym $down       resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym $up         resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym $right      resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        # same bindings, but for the arrow keys
        bindsym Left        resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Down        resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Up          resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Right       resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        # back to normal: Enter or Escape or $mod+r
        bindsym Return mode "default"
        bindsym Escape mode "default"
        bindsym $mod+r mode "default"
}

bindsym $mod+Shift+s mode "resize"

# Start i3bar to display a workspace bar (plus the system information i3status
# finds out, if available)
bar {
  font pango:Exo2, FontAwesome5Free, FontAwesome5Brands, SymbolsNerdFont 12
    status_command i3blocks
    position bottom
}
# for polybar
# exec_always --no-startup-id $HOME/polybar-collection/launch.sh



# a mode to exit, more practical that the $mod+Shift+e that forces the use of mouse.
mode "exit: [l]ogout, [r]eboot, [s]hutdown" {
  bindsym l exec i3-msg exit
  bindsym r exec systemctl reboot
  bindsym s exec systemctl poweroff
  bindsym Escape mode "default"
  bindsym Return mode "default"
  bindsym $mod+x mode "default"
}
# I added fullscreen disable in order for the message to always be visible
bindsym $mod+x fullscreen disable mode "exit: [l]ogout, [r]eboot, [s]hutdown"
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `gnome-characters`:

```
sudo pacman -Syu gnome-characters
```

To type the character use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> then [type the code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin-1_Supplement).

e,g:

<kbd>ê</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> `00EA`

<kbd>ë</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> `00EB`

<kbd>Û</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> `00DB`

Comment: Thanks. This indeed work, but it is "usual" in all my other OS to simply use ^+e for that, and it is way more convenient, as this accent is often used in french.